# method undefined errors when creating component classes in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I've been working on a new React project and I've hit the same problem a few times: class methods not being "seen" by the class component at compile time. For example:

```
  class CategoryList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // this.renderListItem = this.renderListItem.bind(this);
  }

  renderListItem({category}) {
    return <a href="#" className="list-group-item" key={category} >{category}</a>;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="list-group">
          {this.props.categories.map(renderListItem)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default CategoryList;
```

Yields a compilation error:

```
6:3   warning  Useless constructor              no-useless-constructor
20:38  error    'renderListItem' is not defined  no-undef
```

Note that for such a simple module I can of course avoid the whole thing by putting the renderListItem() code in render(), it's a style thing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`renderListItem` defined as `CategoryList` method., in order to call it in `render` you need to use `this`

```
 {this.props.categories.map(this.renderListItem)}
                            ^^^^^
```